# Method overloading toString()

Tags: java

Hi I was just wondering if it is possible to have multiple toString() methods in the same class. The two different toString() methods print different things. ex:

```
public String toString(){
    return String.format("(%.1f%+.1fi)%n", real, imaginary);
}

public String toString(){
    return String.format("z=%.3f(cos(%.3f)+isin(%.3f))%n",real,imaginary,imaginary);
}
```

Comment: its better if you either declare them as constants/final or pass them as arguments.

Comment: avoid hardcoding info, also what if you need to make change to your cos function, are you going to change it manually across the entire project. Make it as a final and use it everywhere.

Comment: No you cannot use this .however, you can try parameters which is function overloading, `public String toString(String s){
    return String.format("x,y,z");
} `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't have two methods with the same name and signature.

A "signature" in this case means the number of arguments and their types.  Changing this won't allow you to override `toString()` twice, it'll just make one a normal method.

```
public String toString(){
    return String.format("(%.1f%+.1fi)%n", real, imaginary);
}

public String toString( boolean fubar ){
    return String.format("z=%.3f(cos(%.3f)+isin(%.3f))%n",real,imaginary,imaginary);
}
```

The second method has a different signature, so it's legal, but doesn't override `toString()`.

Comment: Could you have it with different signature if so can you show me a example on how I can use it. Thank You

Comment: The second method I posted overloads `toString()`, not overrides it.  Overrides is normally what you want with `toString()`.  Really, the second method should be named something totally different just to avoid this sort of confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a toString() method that takes an argument to indicate the expected format of the output.
Say you have 3 formats. You can have an enum and based on the value you get, you print/return the value in that format.

### EDIT 1

Let's say you have an enum

```
public enum PrintFormat{
    F1, F2, F3
}
```

and the toString() method that you're going to overload

```
public toString(PrintFormat format){
    switch(format){
        case F1:
           //return in a diff format
        case F2:
           //return in a diff format
        //so on so forth
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give me a example of this.

Comment: Thank you I will use this its helpfull

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to overrides multiple toString() in the same Class